# Copying large number of directories with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I developed a [SuperflyCSS CLI](https://github.com/superflycss/cli/blob/master/index.js) command line utility and one of the things it does is copy all directories and files from `src/main/css` to `dist` using the `sfc dist` command.  The Node package used for the copy is [copy-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-dir) and the command run is `require('copy-dir').sync(PLI.src.main.css, PLI.DIST);`.

I then developed a script that builds css utilities for all google fonts at various font weights and it generates 176691  directories for each font at a certain font weight.  Each directory has a tiny file in it.  [This is the script](https://github.com/superflycss/utilities-fonts/blob/master/src/main/js/index.js) that generates the directories and corresponding files.

It seems both [Ubuntu's cp command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217764/argument-list-too-long-when-copying-files) and the utility I'm using in Node have a hard time copying this many directories.  So I'm looking for an 'rsync' like solution for Node.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The [recursive-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-copy) package handles it.  Ended up using it like this:

```
    rcopy(PLI.src.main.css, PLI.DIST, function(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Prepublished command failed: ' + error);
        } else {
            console.info('Prepublished ' + results.length + ' files');
        }
    });
```